# Executing an Oracle Stored Procedure from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, t-sql

how do we execute an Oracle Stored Procedure from SQL Server 2005?
As part of a SQL Server scripts we need to execute an Oracle 10g Stored Procedure and download data to SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can still use `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORA_SERVER, 'EXECUTE sp;')` to acomplish this.

Comment: John one quick question.  I run the above scripts and it prompt me this error message:
Cannot process the object "EXECUTE xxxx(SYSDATE - 40, SYSDATE );". The OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "lumd" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

How do I link to Oracle Server from SQL Server?

Comment: Can you post the whole query?  I would be inclined to believe that the error message is telling the truth. ;)

Comment: Also, what happens when you execute the query using Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: Here:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(lumd, 'execute REP.T2t.collect_all(SYSDATE - 40, SYSDATE );')

Comment: Can you confirm if you have successfully executed an oracle stored procedure from sql server using the open query function. If yes, How? because I am having problems executing stored procedures with arguments using the OPENQUERY Function.

Comment: I'm not an oracle guru, but if you can `select 1 "Result" from dual` on success and `select 0 "Result" from dual` on failure, you can just check that.